# How to PERMANENTLY delete chunks in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I have seen video and such on how to prune chunks and replace them with the newest versions but I still don't really know if it is possible to permanently delete chunks off a world. For myself, I need to delete any chunks outside of 25k blocks of 0,0,0. This meaning that there are no blocks outside those chunks and is just empty void (Like a skyblock world). MCedit is obviously way out of date so using that is out of the option.

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Region_file_format#Region_file_location

Comment: @FabianRöling Despite the misleading title, the user isn't asking how to delete chunks, but instead how to fill them with air, so just deleting region files doesn't work.

Comment: @pppery Ah ok. I read "delete chunks" and "replace them with the newest version" (sounds like regenerating them).

Answer (score 2):

If it is a completely void world you seek, there is just the thing already in the game!

1. Click "Create New World"
2. Click "More World Options"
3. Change the World type from "Deafult" to "Superflat"
4. Click the "Customise" button below it
5. Click the "Presets" button
6. Scroll down the list until you see the preset "The Void"
7. Click on "The Void" preset
8. Then press "Use Preset"
9. Click "Done"
10. Change any other settings you would like
11. Click "Create New World"!

You will spawn on a 32x32 platform made out of stone with random blocks of cobblestone mixed in. The entire world is completely void, no Bedrock, no structures, Nothing.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, and thanks for your helpful answer!